# Does zero vector in the span

Tags: linear-algebra

This is seems to be an trivial question, I just want to know does zero vector always in the span since we could produce zero vector by multiply zero in each component of the basis set.

Comment: Yes.  Note that the span is a vector space, which must contain the zero vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If our set $S$ is non-empty than it's pretty straight-forward that $0\in S$. If $S=\emptyset$, then the question gets trickier. The answer is still "yes",but some thought needs to be done. Normally you write:

$$\langle S \rangle=\langle v_1,...,v_n\rangle=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i:a_i\in F\right\}$$

A more general notation:
$$\langle S \rangle=\langle v_1,...,v_n\rangle=\left\{\sum_{i\in \{1,...,n\}} a_iv_i:a_i\in F\right\}$$
So if our set is empty:
$$\langle S \rangle=\langle \emptyset \rangle=\left\{\sum_{i\in \emptyset} a_iv_i:a_i\in F\right\}$$
So our sum has no summands!(it's an empty sum)
What's the value of an empty sum?
Well obviously if the sum is empty we would like that:
$$1+\sum_{i\in \emptyset} \alpha_i=1$$
So the only meaningful definition is:
$$\sum_{i\in \emptyset} \alpha_i=0$$
And this means that:
$$\langle S \rangle=\langle \emptyset \rangle=\{0:a_i\in F\}=\{0\}$$
It's always an interesting logic exercise to reason on this kind of subtleties. If you want a little challenge, what should be the value of an empty product?
$$\prod_{i \in \emptyset} \alpha_i=?$$
(However this is more than a mental exercise, the fact that $\langle \emptyset \rangle=\{0\}$, guarantees the existence of a basis of the null vector space)

Answer (score 0):

You observe correctly that the zero vector is always in the span (of a set of vectors) since it is the "zero combination" of the vectors in that set.

---

By definition, given a set of vectors, $S=\{v_1,\cdots, v_n\}$ where $v_k$ are vectors in a vector space $V$ (over a field $F$),
$$
\textrm{span}(S):=\{\sum_{k=1}^n a_kv_k:a_k\in F\}
$$
So
$$
0=0v_1+\cdots+0v_n\in \textrm{span}(S)
$$

Comment: You might want to explain what happens in the situation where $S$ is empty.